# Fazer um Get no webclient passando json como parametro

Tags: java, json, spring

Estou fazendo a requisição dessa forma, porém não estou tendo sucesso , alguém que já tenha passado por isso?

```
private static String vwsApiUrl = "http://vws.veloxtickets.com:82/wscinema.ws/Get_Cinema_Programacao";

 String url = "'{\"AUTENTICACAO\":{\"USUARIO\":\"SONAE\",\"SENHA\":\"senha\"},\"GETPROG\":{\"DATAINI\":\"2018-07-05\",\"DATAFIN\":\"2018-07-08\",\"CODPRACA\":\"PLZ\"}}'";

 Disposable webClient = WebClient.create(vwsApiUrl  )
                .method (  HttpMethod.GET)
                .uri ( vwsApiUrl + url)
                .contentType ( MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
                .accept ( MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8 )
                .exchange ()
                .flatMap ( clientResponse ->  clientResponse.bodyToMono ( String.class ) ).subscribe ( System.out::println );
```

Esse json foi em outra tentativa , mas passei tbm o url ,e retorna um erro :

> Exception in thread "restartedMain"
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException Caused by:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not enough variable values
>   available to expand '"DATAINI"' at
>   org.springframework.web.util.UriComponents$VarArgsTemplateVariables.getValue(UriComponents.java:352)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.util.UriComponents.expandUriComponent(UriComponents.java:252)

Comment: Introduza um pouco mais de contexto, dessa forma quem lê pode se identificar melhor. 
O que vc busca ? Pra que ? Como ? o que usa ?

Comment: `.uri ( vwsApiUrl + json )` - tem certeza que é isso que você queria? Observe que o seu JSON está na variável `url` que você não usa em lugar nenhum, enquanto que a variável `json`, só com esse código não dá para saber o que é pois não está definida em lugar nenhum. Além disso eu acho que concatenar um JSON na URL desse jeito é algo no mínimo estranho.

Comment: Está recebendo algum erro ao fazer isto?

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa substituir os `\"` por `\\\"`:

```
 String url = "'{\"AUTENTICACAO\":{\"USUARIO\":\"SONAE\",\"SENHA\":\"senha\"},\"GETPROG\":{\"DATAINI\":\"2018-07-05\",\"DATAFIN\":\"2018-07-08\",\"CODPRACA\":\"PLZ\"}}'";
 String urlEscapada = url.replace("\"", "\\\"");
```

Diferença entre `url` e o `urlEscapada`, respectivamente:

```
'{"AUTENTICACAO":{"USUARIO":"SONAE","SENHA":"senha"},"GETPROG":{"DATAINI":"2018-07-05","DATAFIN":"2018-07-08","CODPRACA":"PLZ"}}'

'{\"AUTENTICACAO\":{\"USUARIO\":\"SONAE\",\"SENHA\":\"senha\"},\"GETPROG\":{\"DATAINI\":\"2018-07-05\",\"DATAFIN\":\"2018-07-08\",\"CODPRACA\":\"PLZ\"}}'
```

Utilizando a `urlEscapada`:

```
Disposable webClient = WebClient.create(vwsApiUrl  )
            .method (  HttpMethod.GET)
            .uri ( vwsApiUrl + urlEscapada)
            .contentType ( MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
            .accept ( MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8 )
            .exchange ()
            .flatMap ( clientResponse ->  clientResponse.bodyToMono ( String.class ) ).subscribe ( System.out::println );
```